# How to save HTTPS protocol after proxy_pass to HTTP protocol?

Tags: nginx, proxy, stream, proxypass, kaltura

I have 3 docker containers in the same network:

1. **Storage** (golang) - it provides API for uploading video files.
2. **Streamer** (nginx) - it streams uploaded files
3. **Reverse Proxy** (let's call it just Proxy)

I have `HTTPS` protocol between User and Proxy.

Let's assume that there is a file with **id=c14de868-3130-426a-a0cc-7ff6590e9a1f** and User wants to see it. So User makes a request to `https://stream.example.com/hls/master.m3u8?id=c14de868-3130-426a-a0cc-7ff6590e9a1f`. **Streamer** knows video id (from query param), but it doesn't know the path to the video, so it makes a request to the storage and exchanges video id for the video path. Actually it does proxy_pass to `http://docker-storage/getpath?id=c14de868-3130-426a-a0cc-7ff6590e9a1f`.

> docker-storage in an upstream server. And protocol is http, because
>   I have no SSL-connection between docker containers in local network.

After **Streamer** gets path to the file it starts streaming. But User's browser start throwing `Mixed Content Type` error, because the first request was throw `HTTPS` and after proxy_pass it became `HTTP`.

Here is nginx.conf file (it is a **Streamer** container):

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
  use epoll;
}

http {
  error_log stderr debug;

  default_type application/octet-stream;

  sendfile    on;
  tcp_nopush  on;
  tcp_nodelay on;

  vod_mode                           local;
  vod_metadata_cache                 metadata_cache 16m;
  vod_response_cache                 response_cache 512m;
  vod_last_modified_types            *;
  vod_segment_duration               9000;
  vod_align_segments_to_key_frames   on;
  vod_dash_fragment_file_name_prefix "segment";
  vod_hls_segment_file_name_prefix   "segment";

  vod_manifest_segment_durations_mode accurate;

  open_file_cache          max=1000 inactive=5m;
  open_file_cache_valid    2m;
  open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
  open_file_cache_errors   on;

  aio on;

  upstream docker-storage {
    # There is a docker container called storage on the same network
    server storage:9000;
  }

  server {
    listen 9000;
    server_name localhost;
    root /srv/static;

    location = /exchange-id-to-path {
      proxy_pass $auth_request_uri;
      proxy_pass_request_body off;

      proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;

      # I tried to experiment with this header
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

      set $filepath $upstream_http_the_file_path;
    }

    location /hls {
      # I use auth_request module just to get the path from response header (The-File-Path)
      set $auth_request_uri "http://docker-storage/getpath?id=$arg_id";
      auth_request /exchange-id-to-path;
      auth_request_set $filepath $upstream_http_the_file_path;

      # Here I provide path to the file I want to stream
      vod hls;
      alias $filepath/$arg_id;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot from browser console:
[image: photo]

Here is the response from success (200) request:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1470038,RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=25.000,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2"
http://stream.example.com/hls/index-v1-a1.m3u8

#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=171583,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.4d401f",URI="http://stream.example.com/hls/iframes-v1-a1.m3u8"
```

**The question is how to save https protocol after proxy_pass to http?**

**p.s.** I use [Kaltura nginx-vod-module](https://github.com/kaltura/nginx-vod-module) for streaming video files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `proxy_pass` isn't the problem here. When the vod module returns the index path it uses an absolute URL with `HTTP` protocol. A relative URL should be enough since the index file and the chunks are under the same domain (if I understood it correctly).

Try setting `vod_hls_absolute_index_urls off;` (and `vod_hls_absolute_master_urls off;` as well), so your browser should send requests relative to `stream.example.com` domain using `HTTPS`.